# The french babel gives me a missing \begin{document}

Tags: babel, languages

My impression is that is an already answered question. However, I am really stuck with this:

This code:

```
\documentclass[french]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
uniquename=false,
uniquelist=false,
style=apa,
doi=false,
isbn=false,
url=false,
maxcitenames=3,
uniquelist=false,
natbib]{biblatex}

    %%Bibliography format
\addbibresource{allbiblio.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{frenchb}{american-apa}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{labelmonth}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{note}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{frenchb}{bibliography = {Bibliographie}, references = {Références},}


\begin{document}

\lipsum

An example of citation \citet{Aslin1998}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

gives the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.515   \StartBabelCommands*{\BabelLanguages}{d
                                               ate}
```

I tried some other thing in place of "french" :

- "francais" and "frenchb" give the same output
- Other language as "english", "canadian"... are ok when I delete the .aux files

And when I try to just remove the babel package :

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
uniquename=false,
uniquelist=false,
style=apa,
doi=false,
isbn=false,
url=false,
maxcitenames=3,
uniquelist=false,
natbib]{biblatex}

    %%Bibliography format
\addbibresource{allbiblio.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{frenchb}{american-apa}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{labelmonth}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{note}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{frenchb}{bibliography = {Bibliographie}, references = {Références},}


\begin{document}

\lipsum

An example of citation \citet{Aslin1998}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I can't get rid of this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \mkbibdateapalongextra 
                                  {labelyear}{labelmonth}{labelday}\iffieldu...
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to create document in french (and keep the american APA formatting for the bibliography) ?

Comment: Works fine here (TeX Live 2013). However, I get the same kind of error as your first one sometimes, when the .aux file is corrupted. What happens if you remove the .aux file and then typeset again?

Comment: I tried to remove the .aux files without any success. Do you think the problem could be the distribution I use (TeXworks) ?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I can't confirm the behaviour you described, but I do not have your `bib` file at hand, so perhaps there is something strange within your `bib` file? Otherwise the compilation works.

Comment: This also works fine for me, I suspect the `bib` file has something wrong with it; try with an empty one and then add half the entries.

Comment: Indeed I put the bibliography lines to illustrate the second problem. The first one remain even when the code contain only the \usepackage{babel}...